# What is the difference between library and model in CodeIgniter Framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI. Before I had worked extensively in RoR and Symfony.

I am unable to understand why exactly CI provides Library and Models. Most of the CI code I examined generally used Library as a Wrapper around Model. Models are exclusively kept for talking to database.

Can someone throw light on this ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are probably other schools of thought on this, but for me it's as follows:

### Models

Models are tightly coupled to your application, making direct references to your DB schema/architecture/file paths etc.

### Libraries

Libraries are loosely coupled.  They should be treated like 3rd party add-ons and should make no assumptions about your app or your system.  You should be able to "drop in" libraries at will with a minimum amount of configuration. Indeed, the opposite should be true, items in your library folder should be able to be dropped into any other CI application.

Comment: With reference to your view on library, I thought the said functionality was achieved through "modules" in CI.

Comment: @Akshar There is some overlap in concepts at times, but a library can be thought of as a singleton class that is mostly (if not fully) independent of that particular CI application. There are no strict rules as to what you can do with a library, but if you want an idea of what a library should do, take a look at some of the native CI libraries, like the image_lib.

Answer (score 2):

The basci thought on **Libraries** was a way to extend Codeigniter's functionality through classes.

If you compare the blank anatomy of a **Library** and a **Model** in Codeigniter, you will see that Models extend the **CI_MODEL** which allows you to access Codeigniter's native resources (for Example *$this->db*).

Libraries do not offer that basic access and they also do not need to be extended through the **CI_MODEL**.

Models are made to depict and interact with data (mostly abstracted from databases such as mysql).

Take a look at the basic **Library**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Library{

   public function MyFunction(){
      //do something...
   }

}
```

...and the **Model** anatomy

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

   public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();            
    }

    public function MyFunction(){
        //do something...
    }
}
```

In most cases the Models are prepared to use Ressources to access databases or other functionalities. Libraries don't. You need to include or extend the Ressources manually if you need them:

```
//Create an CI instance
$CI =& get_instance();
```

**Libraries** are tool collections and function extensions while **Models** are natively ideal for abstracting and interacting with data coming from databases.