# What are the difference between model and library in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks

I am little confusing about the usage of model and library in Codeigniter framework..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between library and model in CodeIgniter Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246609/what-is-the-difference-between-library-and-model-in-codeigniter-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Models and libraries are not so different technically. The difference is more conceptual. A library is expected to be easily re-usable. A model is not. It can be very specific to your application. That’s the difference.

Comment: Thanks Vinod, Can you explain briefly about the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246712

> #### Models:
>
> Models are tightly coupled to your application, making direct references to your DB schema/architecture/file paths etc.
>
> #### Libraries:
>
> Libraries are loosely coupled. They should be treated like 3rd party add-ons and should make no assumptions about your app or your system. You should be able to "drop in" libraries at will with a minimum amount of configuration. Indeed, the opposite should be true, items in your library folder should be able to be dropped into any other CI application.